# Converting user input to hex - ESP32 IDF

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I'm trying to build a function that accepts commands using UART and extracts a sub string from the command to write it into ESP32 EFUSE.

```
static void uart_event_task()
{
    uart_event_t event;
    size_t buffered_size;
    uint8_t *dtmp = (uint8_t *)malloc(RD_BUF_SIZE);
    char cmd[30];
    char serialNum[20];
    for (;;)
    {
        // Waiting for UART event.
        if (xQueueReceive(uart0_queue, (void *)&event, (TickType_t)portMAX_DELAY))
        {
            bzero(dtmp, RD_BUF_SIZE);
            ESP_LOGI(TAG_CONFIG, "uart[%d] event:", EX_UART_NUM);
            switch (event.type)
            {
            // Event of UART receving data
            /*We'd better handler data event fast, there would be much more data events than
            other types of events. If we take too much time on data event, the queue might
            be full.*/
            case UART_DATA:
                ESP_LOGI(TAG_CONFIG, "[UART DATA]: %d", event.size);
                uart_read_bytes(EX_UART_NUM, dtmp, event.size, portMAX_DELAY);
                ESP_LOGI(TAG_CONFIG, "[DATA EVT]:");
                // char data = (const char) dtmp;
                // printf("letter: %s", data);
                // int evSize = event.size;
                int lastChar = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= event.size; i++)
                {
                    const char letter = (const char)dtmp[i];
                    if (dtmp[i] == 10 || dtmp[i] == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    cmd[i] = letter;
                    lastChar = i;
                }
                cmd[++lastChar] = '\0';

                ESP_LOGE(TAG_CONFIG, "Your command: %s ", cmd);

                if (strstr(cmd, set_serial) != NULL)
                {
                    // contains
                    int lastChar2 = 0;
                    for (int i = strlen(set_serial) + 1; i < lastChar; i++)
                    {
                        int index = i - strlen(set_serial) - 1;
                        serialNum[index] = cmd[i];
                        lastChar2 = index;
                    }
                    serialNum[++lastChar2] = '\0';
                    ESP_LOGW(TAG_CONFIG, "setting serial: %s ", serialNum);
                    int len = strlen(serialNum);
                    char hex_str[(len * 2) + 1];
                    // converting ascii string to hex string
                    string2hexString(serialNum, hex_str);
                    printf("serialNum: %s\n", serialNum);
                    printf("hex_str: %s\n", hex_str);


                    esp_efuse_coding_scheme_t coding_scheme = esp_efuse_get_coding_scheme(EFUSE_BLK3);
                    write_efuse_fields(serialNum, coding_scheme);
                }
```

This function works perfectly and I can print the serial number as string or as hex:

```
serialNum: exampleserial123
hex_str: 6578616D706C6573657269616C313233
```

The next function writes this data to the efuse of the esp:

```
static void write_efuse_fields(char *serial_num, esp_efuse_coding_scheme_t coding_scheme)
{
    // uint8_t unique_id[16] = {0x48, 0x42, 0x30, 0x31, 0x39, 0x39, 0x39, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33};
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(esp_efuse_write_field_blob(ESP_EFUSE_USER_DATA, &serial_num, 128));

}
```

when I read the efuse block after running the above code:

```
ee 17 fd 3f 00 00 00 ff e4 38 fd 3f 0f 00 00 00
```

Hex to text: îý?ÿä8ý?

If I use the hex output in write_efuse_fields(**hex_str**, coding_scheme)

I will get:

```
90 17 fd 3f 00 00 00 ff e4 38 fd 3f 0f 00 00 00
```

Hex to text: ý?ÿä8ý?

When I do:

```
uint8_t unique_id[16] = {0x48, 0x42, 0x30, 0x31, 0x39, 0x39, 0x39, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33};
ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(esp_efuse_write_field_blob(ESP_EFUSE_USER_DATA, &unique_id, 128));
```

I get the expected result.

What is the correct way to convert my char array to a byte like array (similar to unique_id) to get the esp_efuse_write_field_blob to accept it?

Comment: Fuses are either intact or blown. "Write once, read many"... Time to order another ESP device. You only get one chance per device.

Comment: This is true and I've burnt like 4 already thinking I got the code right this time. but you can enable a virtual efuse using menuconfig, and thats what i'm doing now till I get a solution

Comment: I'm in over my head with blowing ESP fuses, but... That `string2hexString()` gives me the willies... In your "working" example, you write a number of 8 bit bytes (hex 0x00 to 0xFF) and say that works... Why convert the serial number string to a sting twice as long?? You could simply write the ASCII values of "exampleserial123". Why complicate things changing the first 'e' to two bytes that will be ASCII '6' and '5' (if it works)?? ('e' == 0x65 ASCII).

Comment: string2hexString() is a function I got from the internet (sprintf((char *)(output + i), "%02X", input[loop]);) . My question is how do I get the 0x65 from e?

Comment: The value of the ASCII character 'e' **is** 0x65. No conversion necessary. Google "ASCII table" where you'll see the hex, decimal and octal and binary values (and names) of the ASCII character set.

Comment: You could post the revised code as an answer to this question for the benefit of those who find themselves in a similar predicament. Glad it works. The ESPs already 'fused' can be set up to 'blink' and saved for next year's Christmas tree... :-) (I've got one on my desk that's flashing out "Merry Christmas" in Morse code right now... )